# What is a good way to generate code to interface with a running cpp application that doesn't require a recompile?

Tags: python, c++, c, lua

#### I'm attempting to create a back end framework to interact with hardware over a serial connection. I need to be able to specify exactly how these hardware modules will interact without recompilation and running on a system with limited resources.

I already have the cpp code that is being re-used that interacts with the hardware and has the broad functionality to send messages to the devices.

Run-time impact is a serious consideration and it is running on a very limited arch distro that we don't want to change too much for hardware reasons.

It would make the most sense to me to interface with a scripting language that can be easily generated to have a set of references to the cpp base that can be loaded on command.  *(Sort of like a plugin system)*

**Python** - is a really good option but I have almost no experience working with embedded python, I have looked into it and I guess where I might be confused is how the interpreted script would link to functionality in the original program without something like pybind11 and embedded python both working together. Binder certainly has a appeal. No Boost please - *maybe a little*.

**LUA** - is a robust option that is well tested but a little more difficult to generate on command. LuaBridge also has the functionality that I desire. Biggest concern is run time impact but I'm not an expert of course.

**Just make the whole thing in cpp and load libraries like a regular person** - solid option but likely the most difficult to generate and run syntax checks on easily.

**Make the entire thing in a scripting language and get rid of the overhead of a compiler** - I mean technically this is a option

These of course aren't all of the options but this is by far out of my area of expertise and I think it would be beneficial to discuss.

I would really like to know what I should spend my time researching. I have spent far too much time already looking into pybind and I find myself not being able to sleep easy at night.

Ideally this workflow would run somewhat like this:

*On the main Controller* :

1. Interface program is run (cpp)
2. Interface program does diagnostics and checks module status (already done)
3. Interface checks for run script to execute module functionality

*The Script* :

1. Generated from some source
2. Runs tests to verify generation does not have syntactical mistakes
3. Gets moved into a folder where the Interface program can grab it (In a "totally" safe way) *I'm kidding I know the issues with that setup but we aren't considering it at this moment*

That was super long and I'm sorry I'm just very lost and out of my comfort zone.

Yeah I'm sorry I didn't clarify why generated code was important. We built a very simple top level gui to interact with the hardware and that needs to be translated into a script to interact with the main interface for the controller.

Another option I came up with last night:

**Write a very simple custom scripting langauge that I can parse on the cpp side and link that way**

Comment: I can use cpp11 - cpp17 if that somehow impacts a decision.

Comment: While I don't know a lot about [tag:LUA], it sounds like a solid choice of the ones you list. [tag:python] is not really ideal for embedding AFAIK - my guess is it will be a tough fight. Also, I would be more worried about python performance since you mention that is an issue. So why are you concerned about [tag:LUA] runtime impact ?

Comment: I had similar problem to solve. In my case I needed to interact with a signal processing Verilog code implemented on FPGA, using a Qt (C++) designed GUI. The aim was to change the functionality of architecture and data being used to be processed using the GUI. I used dual port RAM in which C++ code can store and modify the content from one port (by memory mapping), running signal processing code used to read instructions from the RAM and work accordingly. In contrast I used RAM as an interface (direct access is required)

Comment: It’s not clear why you need to *generate* code here.  If you just want to avoid recompilation and you don’t want to spend a lot of time on the interface, it sounds like you just want [SWIG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG).

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating a script, you can probably simplify things to a simple byte code that gets interpreted. Then you don't have to mess with parsing or syntax validation. Each "instruction" can be a simple opcode followed by zero or more operands, where each operand will be an integer, float or string (and any other primitive data types that your hardware supports/needs). You can use something like msgpack for encoding and decoding instructions compactly.

If that model works, you can gradually add tools on the developer side, such as a minimal assembler, or even a script interpreter that generates the byte code and thus avoids any complexity within your constrained hardware environment.